# Create array of individual hashes from one hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Given a hash of key/value pairs, how can I turn that into an array of individual hashes for each key/value pair.

So for example, starting with:

```
{"hello"=>"bonjour", "goodbye"=>"au revoir"}
```

And turning that into:

```
[ {"hello" => "bonjour"}, {"goodbye" => "au revoir"} ]
```

I got that with the following but am wondering if there's an easier approach:

```
array = []
hash.each do |k,v|
  h = Hash.new
  h[k] = v
  array << h
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Do as below using [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map_):

```
h = {"hello"=>"bonjour", "goodbye"=>"au revoir"}
h.map { |k,v| { k => v } }
# => [{"hello"=>"bonjour"}, {"goodbye"=>"au revoir"}]
```